# VB grab text values and save as variables

Tags: xml, vb.net, substring, streamreader

I was wondering if there is a quicker way to "search" part of a line's string of text and find non-static values and save them to variables?

For instance, I can't really use Substring and search for part of a line because the values in the " " are never the same length.

Example part of the text file that I am reading in:

```xml
<I_Sect IDCode="20001" Description="This is desc" Quantity="1000" InclKind="Inc" />
```

The id names : `IDCode Description Quantity and InclKind` never change

The values do change: `20001 ... This is desc... etc`

Is there a quicker way to search the "" after I do a substring to find the id name and grab how ever long the string between the "" is?

Current code:

```vb
Dim list As New List(Of String)()
Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(DisplayFile)
While Not file.EndOfStream
    Dim line As String = file.ReadLine()
    list.Add(line)
End While
file.Close()
Console.WriteLine("{0} lines read", list.Count)
'RichTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(DisplayFile)

For counter As Integer = 0 To list.Count

    If list(counter).Substring(0, 7) = "<I_Sect" Then
        'Do a substring of the line to see if I can locate Description ID string

        ' .............

        Dim desc As String = ' .... [the valve I grab will be "This is desc"]
    End If

Next
```

Comment: What does your entire xml file look like (minimal example showing all possible nodes)?

Comment: The xml file is semi long but I am only looking at this one line. So when my code reads line by line and catches it starting with <I_Sect then I will just grab indexes of that line only @Verdolino

Comment: Fair enough, but I always suggest using xml serialization when reading xml, and that requires knowing the entire schema - or at least the subset you are interested in.

Comment: I understand. My current Schema is very standard [aka only one main element that I have to search and grab all the ID values] I know right now I could just try and find a more "structured" sub string search but I will assign the IDCode, Description and etc as new variables. So I need a less "structured" sub string check so I can get all ID values since the values are not a static length @Verdolino

Comment: So far I am at this point:

    `Dim startCheck = list(counter).Trim
    If startCheck.Contains("IDCode") Then
                    Dim IDindex As Integer = startCheck.IndexOf("IDCode")
                    If IDindex >= 0 Then
                        Dim IDCode As String = startCheck.Substring(IDindex + 7 .......
                    End If
                End If`

However, I am trying to find a way to get those values in-between "" @Verdolino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <I_SecMain>
    <I_SecTop>
      <I_SecBrac>
        <I_Sect IDCode="20001" Description="This is desc 1" Quantity="10001" InclKind="Inc 1" />
        <I_Sect IDCode="20002" Description="This is desc 2" Quantity="10002" InclKind="Inc 2" />
        <I_Sect IDCode="20003" Description="This is desc 3" Quantity="10003" InclKind="Inc 3" />
        <I_Sect IDCode="20004" Description="This is desc 4" Quantity="10004" InclKind="Inc 4" />
        <I_Sect IDCode="20005" Description="This is desc 5" Quantity="10005" InclKind="Inc 5" />
      </I_SecBrac>
    </I_SecTop>
  </I_SecMain>
</root>
```

You can define a corresponding model you can use to deserialize the file.

Imported namespaces

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
```

Model

```vb
<XmlRoot("root")>
Public Class Root
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property I_SecMain As I_SecMain
End Class

Public Class I_SecMain
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property I_SecTop As I_SecTop
End Class

Public Class I_SecTop
    <XmlElement>
    Public Property I_SecBrac As I_SecBrac
End Class

Public Class I_SecBrac
    <XmlElement("I_Sect")>
    Public Property I_Sects As List(Of I_Sect)
End Class

Public Class I_Sect
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property IDCode As Integer
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property Description As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property InclKind As String
End Class
```

And very simply deserialize the file into strongly typed objects

```vb
Dim DisplayFile = "test.xml"

Dim myRoot As Root
Dim mySerializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Root))
Using fs As New FileStream(DisplayFile, FileMode.Open)
    myRoot = mySerializer.Deserialize(fs)
End Using
```

which can be iterated over.

```vb
For Each isect In myRoot.I_SecMain.I_SecTop.I_SecBrac.I_Sects
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Format("ID Code: {0}, Description: {1}, Quantity: {2}, InclKind: {3}",
                      isect.IDCode, isect.Description, isect.Quantity, isect.InclKind))
Next
```

From here, it's a matter of defining your model accurately (you didn't post it in your question) and just retrieving properties from the deserialized objects.

Using serialization, it's trivial to write to the file as well, if that's a requirement.

```vb
Using fs As New FileStream(DisplayFile, FileMode.Open)
    mySerializer.Serialize(fs, myRoot)
End Using
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do you put the <XmlRoot..> part in the vb file? It flags saying undefined when transferring it to the "top of the page where the classes are defined".  Same for <XmlAttribute> part too

Comment: That is the model definition. It needs to be in a place where your code can access it and the model's classes must be public. Also you should `Imports System.Xml.Serialization`

Comment: When the model's class name is not spelled exactly the same as the xml schema, you can pass the name. I did this twice; when the root is "root" but I wanted to capitalize the class (depends on your schema) and when I have a list I want to pluralize but the elements have singular names.

Comment: If i am reading your line `mySerializer.Deseriaize` ... it is reading the text file. I already do that with my previous code so is there anyway to read the line i give without that line and do the `String.Format` part? I ask because the `mySerializer.Deserialize` gives an error of `There is an error in XML document (2, 2).`

Comment: also the` Imports System.Xml.Serialization` fixed my previous errors

Comment: Most likely my schema differs from yours and you would need to edit the model accordingly. I wouldn't suggest reading an xml file as text and trying to parse it.

Comment: ok last question then. If i had more <> sections aka roots... does that mean I have to make myRoot..myRoot2.. etc?

Comment: I ask because my schema is `<root> <I_SecMain><I_SecTop> <I_SecBrac> <I_Sect></I_Sect></I_SecBrac></I_SecTop></I_SecMain></root>`

Comment: I edited according to your schema. Note the objects are accessed like this now `myRoot.I_SecMain.I_SecTop.I_SecBrac.I_Sects`

Comment: Oh wow. If you hadn't showed me that I probably wouldn't have known that was how you structured it. thank you for your thorough explanation and example. I still have the `xml document (2,2)` error but I will continue to debug it.